# NUC with Centos 7 crashing: Microcode SW Error Detected

Tags: linux, centos, linux-kernel, intel, iwlwifi

I am trying to figure out why the WiFi on my Intel NUC with CentOS 7 continues to die.  As info, I have 5 node Hadoop cluster and they are all configured the same (as far as I can tell), however, the other machines which are on WiFi do not crash.  I don't know what is wrong with this particular machine.

Here is the error from `/var/log/messages`.  It is the same message that I see regularly as I've been watching this problem for days.

```
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000.
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Status: 0x00000100, count: 6
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 34.0.1
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x000022CE | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x05900280 | trm_hw_status0
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00023FDC | branchlink2
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x0003915A | interruptlink1
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x0000012C | data1
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x03830000 | data2
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | data3
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0xD28011F1 | beacon time
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x72F4FDDD | tsf low
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000182 | tsf hi
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0xCA511FA7 | time gp2
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000022 | uCode version major
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000230 | hw version
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00C89000 | board version
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x0A96001C | hcmd
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0xA7F93882 | isr0
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00050000 | isr1
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x0020180A | isr2
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x40417DCD | isr3
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x0A95001C | last cmd Id
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00004288 | l2p_control
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00018024 | l2p_duration
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x000000EF | l2p_addr_match
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x0000000D | lmpm_pmg_sel
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x30101345 | timestamp
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00007888 | flow_handler
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Status: 0x00000100, count: 7
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000070 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0xC0086964 | umac branchlink2
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0xC0083A94 | umac interruptlink1
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0xC0083A94 | umac interruptlink2
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000800 | umac data1
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0xC0083A94 | umac data2
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000022 | umac major
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac minor
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0xC088628C | frame pointer
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0xC088628C | stack pointer
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00DF019C | last host cmd
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: FW error in SYNC CMD STATISTICS_CMD
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 4898 Comm: NetworkManager Kdump: loaded Not tainted 3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64 #1
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: Hardware name: Intel Corporation NUC7i7BNH/NUC7i7BNB, BIOS BNKBL357.86A.0049.2017.0724.1541 07/24/2017
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: Call Trace:
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffaeb61e41>] dump_stack+0x19/0x1b
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffc0afa983>] iwl_trans_pcie_send_hcmd+0x563/0x580 [iwlwifi]
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffae4c2d00>] ? wake_up_atomic_t+0x30/0x30
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffc0b060fc>] iwl_trans_send_cmd+0x5c/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffc0c6d312>] iwl_mvm_send_cmd+0x32/0xb0 [iwlmvm]
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffc0c6e632>] iwl_mvm_request_statistics+0x72/0x100 [iwlmvm]
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffc0c616fe>] iwl_mvm_mac_sta_statistics+0xbe/0x100 [iwlmvm]
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffc0bb68f7>] sta_set_sinfo+0xb7/0x800 [mac80211]
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffc0bcd052>] ieee80211_get_station+0x52/0x80 [mac80211]
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffc08cae41>] nl80211_get_station+0xa1/0x240 [cfg80211]
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffae794d0d>] ? list_del+0xd/0x30
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffae5bdf1a>] ? __rmqueue+0x8a/0x460
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffaea77918>] genl_family_rcv_msg+0x208/0x430
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffae5bf134>] ? free_one_page+0x2e4/0x310
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffaea77b9b>] genl_rcv_msg+0x5b/0xc0
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffaea73ec0>] ? __netlink_lookup+0xc0/0x110
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffaea77b40>] ? genl_family_rcv_msg+0x430/0x430
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffaea75bab>] netlink_rcv_skb+0xab/0xc0
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffaea760e8>] genl_rcv+0x28/0x40
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffaea75530>] netlink_unicast+0x170/0x210
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffae78c042>] ? memcpy_fromiovec+0x62/0xb0
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffaea758d8>] netlink_sendmsg+0x308/0x420
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffaea73112>] ? netlink_recvmsg+0x212/0x490
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffaea193a6>] sock_sendmsg+0xb6/0xf0
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffaea194f5>] ? sock_recvmsg+0xc5/0x100
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffaea1a269>] ___sys_sendmsg+0x3e9/0x400
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffae656fe0>] ? __pollwait+0xf0/0xf0
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffae68ee1e>] ? ep_poll+0x31e/0x360
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffaea1b921>] __sys_sendmsg+0x51/0x90
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffaea1b972>] SyS_sendmsg+0x12/0x20
Jan  2 08:41:06 mapr04 kernel: [<ffffffffaeb74ddb>] system_call_fastpath+0x22/0x27
```

Where should I start trying to debug?  I can edit the original post with updates.

Here are some things which I think might be helpful:

`uname -a`:

```
Linux mapr04.wired.carnoustie 3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 29 14:49:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`dmesg | grep iwlwifi`:

```
[    3.822041] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: irq 132 for MSI/MSI-X
[    3.831295] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: loaded firmware version 34.0.1 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.924043] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
[    3.984049] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: base HW address: f8:94:c2:5c:07:24
```

Here is the latest error:

```
Here is the latest error:
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: time out after 2000ms.
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Current CMD queue read_ptr 246 write_ptr 247
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Status: 0x00000100, count: 6
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 34.0.1
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000280 | trm_hw_status0
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00023FDC | branchlink2
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x0003915A | interruptlink1
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x0003915A | interruptlink2
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000080 | data2
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x03830000 | data3
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0xD4C029D9 | beacon time
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x456535F1 | tsf low
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x000001BA | tsf hi
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x6D3BFE27 | time gp2
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000022 | uCode version major
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000230 | hw version
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00C89000 | board version
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x0000001C | hcmd
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00012000 | isr0
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x0000180A | isr2
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00417CC0 | isr3
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x0A89001C | last cmd Id
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00004288 | l2p_control
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00018024 | l2p_duration
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x000000EF | l2p_addr_match
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x0000000D | lmpm_pmg_sel
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x30101345 | timestamp
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00002838 | flow_handler
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Status: 0x00000100, count: 7
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000070 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0xC0086964 | umac branchlink2
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0xC0083A94 | umac interruptlink1
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0xC0083A94 | umac interruptlink2
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000800 | umac data1
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0xC0083A94 | umac data2
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000022 | umac major
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac minor
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0xC088628C | frame pointer
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0xC088628C | stack pointer
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00F6019C | last host cmd
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
Jan  5 03:17:01 mapr04 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the wifi drivers cannot manage the wifi hardware in your NUCs.

- Several linux distros can be tried live without installing. I think NUCs have Intel wifi, which should work with built-in linux drivers, but they must be new enough.
- I have a NUC with Intel 6th generation hardware. I have noticed that older versions of operating systems cannot manage the wifi hardware, but newer versions manage it without any tweaks, 'out of the box'.
- Edit 1: I tested with live systems: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS can manage both the wired and wireless hardware of my NUC6i3SYH. Debian 9, Stretch, can manage the wired network automatically. I failed with the wifi, but other people might fix it (I don't know if there is a driver problem or if I cannot manage the user interface for wifi in Debian.)
- Edit 2: I downloaded `CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1810.iso` ran it live and it can manage both the wired and wireless hardware of my NUC6i3SYH. It was started as easily as with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. But I have not tested the stability during a long time.

Edit 3: You should consider that the hardware might be damaged (for example failing when getting hot). But if it works well with another operating system, you can conclude that the hardware is good.

- When was your NUC hardware developed, and when was the CentOS 7 software developed?
- Centos 7 has an old kernel series, 3.10; the kernel version in the live system '1810' is `3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP`. Ubuntu 18.04.1 live has kernel version 4.15.0-29 and an up to date installed system has 4.15.0-43.
- Please try with another operating system with a newer linux kernel with newer hardware drivers.

Comment: You should consider that the hardware might be damaged (for example failing when getting hot). But if it works well with another operating system, you can conclude that the hardware is good.